Pi pico acting as a USB HID keyboard device for windows
I am trying to make a raspberry pi pico act as a USB HID keyboard. To do so I am using freeRTOS and tinyUSB library. So far I managed to make the code work on linux (elementary OS) but not in Windows 11. I fear I must be missing something about the descriptors. I've tried to follow the tinyUSB hid composite example removing (what I think) are the unnecessary parts.
The code for the usb_descriptors.c
#include "tusb.h"

// HID Report Descriptor
uint8_t const desc_hid_report[] = {
    TUD_HID_REPORT_DESC_KEYBOARD()
};

// Device descriptor
tusb_desc_device_t const desc_device = {
    .bLength = sizeof(tusb_desc_device_t),
    .bDescriptorType = TUSB_DESC_DEVICE,
    .bcdUSB = 0x0200,

    .bDeviceClass = TUSB_CLASS_HID,                  // HID class
    .bDeviceSubClass = HID_SUBCLASS_BOOT,            // Boot subclass
    .bDeviceProtocol = HID_ITF_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD,    // Keyboard protocol
    .bMaxPacketSize0 = CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE,

    .idVendor = 0x16c0,                              // Vendor ID
    .idProduct = 0x0001,                             // Product ID
    .bcdDevice = 0x0001,                             // Device release number

    .iManufacturer = 0x01,                           // Manufacturer string index
    .iProduct = 0x02,                                // Product string index
    .iSerialNumber = 0x03,                           // Serial number string index

    .bNumConfigurations = 0x01                       // Number of configurations
};

// Configuration descriptor
uint8_t const desc_configuration[] = {
    // Configuration Descriptor
    TUD_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR(1,                           // Configuration number
                          1,                           // Number of interfaces
                          0,                           // Configuration string index
                          (TUD_CONFIG_DESC_LEN + TUD_HID_DESC_LEN),  // Total length of data for this configuration
                          0,                           // Attributes (bus-powered)
                          100),                        // Maximum power consumption in 2mA units (100 * 2mA = 200mA)

    // HID Descriptor
    TUD_HID_DESCRIPTOR(0,                              // Interface number
                       0,                              // String index
                       HID_ITF_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD,      // Protocol code
                       sizeof(desc_hid_report),        // HID report descriptor length
                       0x81,                           // Endpoint address (IN endpoint)
                       CFG_TUD_HID_EP_BUFSIZE,         // Endpoint size
                       10)                             // Polling interval in milliseconds
};

// String Descriptors
char const* string_desc_arr[] = {
    (const char[]) { 0x09, 0x04 }, // Supported language (English - 0x0409)
    "TinyUSB",                     // Manufacturer string
    "TinyUSB Device",              // Product string
    "123456",                      // Serial number string
};

uint16_t _desc_str[32];

// Device descriptor callback
uint8_t const* tud_descriptor_device_cb(void) {
    return (uint8_t const*)&desc_device;
}

// Configuration descriptor callback
uint8_t const* tud_descriptor_configuration_cb(uint8_t index) {
    (void)index;
    return desc_configuration;
}

// HID report descriptor callback
uint8_t const* tud_hid_descriptor_report_cb(uint8_t instance) {
    (void)instance;
    return desc_hid_report;
}

// Callback invoked when received GET REPORT request
uint16_t tud_hid_get_report_cb(uint8_t instance, uint8_t report_id, hid_report_type_t report_type, uint8_t* buffer, uint16_t reqlen) {
    // Not used in this example, so we return 0
    return 0;
}

// Callback invoked when received SET REPORT request or via OUT endpoint
void tud_hid_set_report_cb(uint8_t instance, uint8_t report_id, hid_report_type_t report_type, uint8_t const* buffer, uint16_t bufsize) {
    // Not used in this example, so we do nothing
}


// String descriptor callback
uint16_t const* tud_descriptor_string_cb(uint8_t index, uint16_t langid) {
    (void) langid;
    size_t chr_count;

    switch ( index ) {
    case 0: // STRID_LANGID
        memcpy(&_desc_str[1], string_desc_arr[0], 2);
        chr_count = 1;
        break;

    default:
        // Note: the 0xEE index string is a Microsoft OS 1.0 Descriptors.
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/microsoft-defined-usb-descriptors

        if ( !(index < sizeof(string_desc_arr) / sizeof(string_desc_arr[0])) ) return NULL;

        const char *str = string_desc_arr[index];

        // Cap at max char
        chr_count = strlen(str);
        size_t const max_count = sizeof(_desc_str) / sizeof(_desc_str[0]) - 1; // -1 for string type
        if ( chr_count > max_count ) chr_count = max_count;

        // Convert ASCII string into UTF-16
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < chr_count; i++ ) {
        _desc_str[1 + i] = str[i];
        }
        break;
    }

    // first byte is length (including header), second byte is string type
    _desc_str[0] = (uint16_t) ((TUSB_DESC_STRING << 8) | (2 * chr_count + 2));

    return _desc_str;
}

The code tsub_config.h
#ifndef _TUSB_CONFIG_H_
#define _TUSB_CONFIG_H_

#define CFG_TUSB_MCU OPT_MCU_RP2040
#define BOARD_DEVICE_RHPORT_NUM 0
#define BOARD_DEVICE_RHPORT_SPEED OPT_MODE_FULL_SPEED

#define CFG_TUSB_RHPORT0_MODE (OPT_MODE_DEVICE | OPT_MODE_FULL_SPEED)

#define CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE 64

// Enable HID and CDC
#define CFG_TUD_CDC               0
#define CFG_TUD_MSC               0
#define CFG_TUD_HID               1
#define CFG_TUD_MIDI              0
#define CFG_TUD_VENDOR            0

#define CFG_TUD_HID_EP_BUFSIZE 64
#define CFG_TUD_CDC_RX_BUFSIZE 64
#define CFG_TUD_CDC_TX_BUFSIZE 64

#endif // _TUSB_CONFIG_H_

Thanks in advance!
